# Is it possible to add two parameters to a list in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out how to add two parameters to a list so I can have them in the same list. I have a list of gameobjects and I want to "pair" a timer to that gameobject so I can see how long it has been in the trigger. I obviously still need to do the timer and stuff (if you have any suggestions on how to do it, please tell me) along with the trigger exit and stuff but here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Grill : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int time = 0; // The amount of time the object was collided with;
    public int maxTime = 20; // The amount of time before the loop stops.

    public List<GameObject> grilledItems = new List<GameObject>();

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Cookable"))
        {
            grilledItems.Add(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a dictionary with the GameObject being the key and the timer the value?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples):

```
new List<(GameObject gameObj, Timer associatedTimer)>();
```

Comment: Oh thanks, could you explain what a Tuple is and how I can use it? I tried doing `public List<GameObject> grilledItems = new List<(GameObject gameObj, Timer associatedTimer)>();` but there is no definition for timer.

Comment: Click on the link I provided.

Comment: Also, I assumed you knew what timer object you were going to use, I'm just showing you how to pair it which was your question.  If you need to know about timers specifically you need to make that clear in your question.

Comment: And also, I think I am going to make my own timer using ints so I mean, there is the error fixed. But can you explain tuples?

Comment: Okay wait, I then did `public List<GameObject> grilledItems = new List<(GameObject gameObj, int timer)>();` and got the error: https://imgur.com/a/Q7MJePW

Comment: It should be public List<(GameObject gameObj, int timer)> grilledItems = new List<(GameObject gameObj, int timer)>();

Comment: I suggest you check out a C# tutorial.  It seems like you need some practice before you move on to more complicated things.

Comment: Okay thanks @rory.ap, I didn't realize though that when I need to add to the list it's gonna make me put in a timer aswell. Is there any way to get around that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should make it so complicated.  If you need it, use a `Map`.  If not structs are your friends.

```
public struct GrilledItemType
{
    public GameObject grilledObject;
    public Timer      timer;
};
```

Then just

```
public List<GrilledItemType> grilledItems = new List<GrilledItemType>();
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks @jiveturkey, but then I get errors when trying to do the following:
`grilledItems.Add(other.gameObject);` in OnTriggerEnter.

Comment: Don't forget, you're not adding gameObject's.  You're adding `GrilledItemType` objects.  So you need `GrilledItemType grilledItem;  grilledItem.grilledObject = gameObject; // Assign your Timer too` then do `grilledItems.Add(grilledItem);`

Comment: Ah right yeah @jiveturkey, but then what about when I am doing this code?
   `private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Cookable"))
        {
            grilledItems.Add(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
`I don't see how I can make this work.

Comment: Ok @jiveturkey little update, I did this code https://paste.myst.rs/7mk but it's a use of an unassigned local variable?

Comment: You need to add a Timer or `grilledItem.timer = null`